# How to Install Matplotlib Basemap Module on Windows 7 with WinPython (or any Python stack install)?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I've found that the Basemap (module for matplotlib and Python) binary installer for Windows cannot detect Python on the system when Python is installed as part of a stack install, like Anaconda or WinPython.  The installer exits, rather than allow you to point to the directory of installation.

I have to therefore install via source.  However, I don't know the method to do this.  The Readme.txt and install instructions don't seem to help.  They simply instruct to "install geos-3.3.3 first" - well, how exactly?  I don't see a setup.py in that directory.

Any help would be great.  (Python 2.7, Win 7, 64b)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I use windows. And my installation failed with official guidance, too. 
Finally I installed Basemap using the following method. Although I am not sure if it will go right for you, I just offer mine.

1. First of all, you must have **pip** in your computer. (It is much easier
   to install, compared with Basemap and other things. And it can be
   used to install many useful packages.)
2. Then go this great link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

   And download the file named "**basemap‑1.1.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl**".
3. Move the .whl file to directory "C:\Python27". (Maybe you
   installed your python in different disk, then change it
   accordingly.)
4. Open terminal. (Use **cmd** or Git Bash or something else.)
5. Use command:

   > pip install basemap‑1.1.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl

Comment: So this worked for me too. After trying out 10 different guides, this was the one that worked. Make sure though to use the correct file, mine was basemap-1.0.8-cp27-none-win32.whl. Thanks for posting this here.

Comment: If you have 32bit python on 64 bit machine you need the 32bit version of basemap. The CP part stands for your python verion (i.e. 2.7 in this case)

Comment: Also, for me it only worked if I installed matplotlib first

Comment: Thank you!! I had been trying various guides for an hour until I found this.  ...A quick note that I needed to install [pyproj](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) before basemap.  Same process, just save the .whl file to your folder, and pip install it.  Without PyProj, I was getting "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1..."

Comment: Do you mean "Move the .whl file" on 3rd step?

Comment: If Python is installed using Cygwin then there is no \Python directory, but instead in 'C:\cygwin64\bin\' - should the WHL file be moved there?

Comment: you can also set a path you wish like:
py -m pip install "C:\maxbook\maxboxpython\basemap-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
then you get:
Successfully built pyshp
Installing collected packages: pyshp, pyproj, basemap
Successfully installed basemap-1.2.0 pyproj-2.1.3 pyshp-2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me using Python 3.10.1.

Setup environment using terminal in Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial):

```
py -3 -m venv .venv
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
.venv\scripts\activate
```

Install basemap using pip:

```
pip install matplotlib
pip install basemap-data
pip install basemap-data-hires
pip install basemap
```

Create file with code from: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html

Remember to select the correct interpreter (In VSCode use Ctrl+Shift+P to select interpreter).

That's it.